# CSS div responsive box

Tags: css, responsive

I would like to make my div (the pink square) responsive and move with the image. I tried with the "absolute" position. However, the square tends to move up instead of adjusting in height. Thanks a lot, here are the codes and the problem in image (It's awful, it's just for practice)  :

**Code**

```css
.responsive .EBatt{
  position: absolute;
  left: 25.1%;
  top: 69%;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 7vh;
  background: #e7a2cc;
  margin : 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 18%;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <img class="img-accueil" src="images/accueil.png">
  <div class="EBatt"></div>
</div>
```

Computeur view :

[image: PC view]

Smartphone view :

[image: Smartphone view]

Comment: you want it to be the same width of the blue/green line above it? I think we need more details about the exact behavior you want

Comment: @duxfox-- Yes ! I want it to follow the width of the line because I'll add a data in the box (for example 75%)

Comment: and is the image the bettery + blue/green line + the circle to the right? aka - is the image composed of all those pieces? or is each one of those pieces its own image

Comment: @duxfox-- It's only 1 image (battery+ line and circle)

Comment: can you upload the full image into the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Please check

You can use `::after` pseudo element.

You can declare your `width` and `height` with %(percentages)

`width:20%;` is 20% of image.width(parent) same in height too

```css
img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin:0;
  background-color: bisque;
}


.responsive {
  margin-inline: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 800px;
}

.responsive::after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 7.5%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: #e7a2cc;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 18%;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
      <img
        class="img-accueil"
        src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x800"
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working in the code snippet but when I try to add it in my css file, it's doing the same thing as my div ...

Comment: If it is working here, it has to be work in your css file too. Probably you forget to add something. Check your code again please. @CorbeauNoiraud

Comment: Maybe the problem is about `min-height`, i edit the code you can check again

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. It's almost working. The only problem is when I switch from the "Computer" view to the "Phone" view, the box moves a little to the right.

Comment: just please inspect the element and check what is changing then tell me about, what changes makes it move to right, so i can help you with that @CorbeauNoiraud

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I discovered another problem. Since you're using "::after" and not a div, I can't write thing in the box (or I just don't know how).  @UPinar

Comment: `content:"";` add inside it `content:"myText";`

Comment: It's a data from a jsQuery. It will not work right ?

Comment: what do you mean by that you can use querySelector and get the item that you want and add a value inside content=""